How do I perform measurements in the X basis for qutrits in cirq?
After applying the hadamard gate to a 0 state qutrit, I should be able to get it into the + state, but how do I then measure the circuit in the X basis as opposed to the computational basis?

Generally, to measure in basis ${|a\rangle, |b\rangle, |c\rangle }$, you should apply a unitary that maps this basis to a computational basis and then measure in the computational basis. If you mapped $|a\rangle \mapsto |0\rangle$ and then measured $0$, then the original state would measure $a$
